# Hyperlink to new workbook not working

Tags: vba, excel, hyperlink, excel-2010

I'm new to Excel so I hope this makes sense. The code below shows a new sheet being created on a specific workbook (separate from the current one) when a button on a user form is clicked. Though, my hyperlink to the sheet created on the separate workbook seems to be broken. What am I doing wrong? Anything helps, thanks!

```
Dim LastRow As Long, ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Sheets("Employee Information")
LastRow = ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1

If Me.cbStores.Value = "Northern" Then
Dim newWB As Workbook
Dim thisWB As Workbook
Set thisWB = ThisWorkbook
Set newWB = GetOrCreateWB("EmployeeTemplates", "C:\Users\...\Folder") '<--| Opening EmployeeTemplates wb
thisWB.Sheets("Template").Copy after:=newWB.Sheets(1)
With ActiveSheet '<--| the just pasted worksheet becomes the active one
.Name = AddEmployeeUF.txtFirstname.Text + AddEmployeeUF.txtMiddleinitial.Text + AddEmployeeUF.txtLastname.Text + "Template" '<--| Name it
ws.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=ws.Range("F" & LastRow), Address:="", SubAddress:=.Name & "!A1", TextToDisplay:="View" '<--| hyperlink to new sheet
End With
End If
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify the workbook path and name in the address `Address:=newWB.Path & "\" & newWB.Name`. To make sure that it does not fail when using spaces in the worksheet name use this for the subaddress `SubAddress:="'" & .Name & "'!A1"`.

This should be the correct way.

```
ws.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=ws.Range("F" & LastRow), Address:=newWB.Path & "\" & newWB.Name, SubAddress:="'" & .Name & "'!A1", TextToDisplay:="View" '<--| hyperlink to new sheet
```

Comment: @ColeGwozdecki What's the value of `.Name`? E.g. `debug.print .Name`

Comment: .Name = AddEmployeeUF.txtFirstname.Text + AddEmployeeUF.txtMiddleinitial.Text + AddEmployeeUF.txtLastname.Text + "Template"

Comment: No that's the formula. But what is its value? What is the name of the sheet when the error occurs?

Comment: That is the name of the sheet. Whatever is typed in those boxes renames the sheet. If first name is Cole, Middle Initial is U, Last name is Gwoz, then the Sheets named ColeUGwozTemplate

Comment: Ok and what did you type into those boxes to produce the error? This is relevant because if I run it with `.Name = "AAA"` it works!

Comment: The same names I posted in my above comment

Comment: I tried it with `.Name = "AAA"` and it worked and even  `.Name = "ColeUGwozTemplate"` works. Please check again carfully if your subaddress is `SubAddress:="'" & .Name & "'!A1"` with `'` before and after `.Name`

Comment: Is yours creating the new sheet in an existing workbook? And is the hyperlink in the original workbook opening the sheet created in the separate existing wb?

Comment: Ahhh I didn't see that. You can not link to a sheet in a new workbook. Only to a sheet within the same workbook or to another workbook/file but then not to a sheet!

Comment: Are you sure? I've read online that you can, but haven't found anything that works with my code.